# How do I make Apache's paths start from root

Tags: apache

Instead of writing "C:/Tomato/root/t.txt" (root being the root of the website), how do I write something like "/t.txt" or "rootvar + 't.txt'" on the configuration files?

I can't find it anywhere. Thank you.

Comment: @covener On the config files. (forgot to add)

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Apache on Windows but I'm guessing the configuration is similar. You need to change one or two things in the config file :-

```
DocumentRoot "C:/Tomato/root"
```

There should also be an entry that matches that path :-

```
<Directory "C:/Tomato/root">
 # Lots of stuff here ...
</Directory>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Write this:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/here.txt'
```